# tweet from WinJS app

Tags: javascript, twitter, oauth, windows-runtime, winjs

I make an app using WinJS on Windows 8 platform and I want to post a simple tweet. I can pass through all `oauth authentication` and I can get the request token just after user enter the PIN code.

But when I try to tweet with I got

> "Could not authenticate you", "code" 32

I put this values:

> URL : https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json Post values:
>   status : "test" Header Authorization: "OAuth
>   oauth_consumer_key=\"XXXXXXXXX\", oauth_nonce=\"160641457\",
>   oauth_signature=\"XXXXXXXXXXX\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",
>   oauth_timestamp=\"1386534245\", oauth_token=\"000000000-XXXXXXXXX\",
>   oauth_version=\"1.0\""

Comment: using a [lib](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries/v1) might  help. nevertheless, in case of twitter - you can't protect your app key if that ships with app.

Comment: I mostly see this done with the share charm built into WinJS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465261.aspx